# sklearn confusion matrix missed some results

Tags: python

i wanted to plot a confusion matrix with my facial expression recognition test results
but the confusion matrix has 7 columns and 6 rows while predicted label and target label have same shape
so i can't see some test accuracy of them in confusion matrix
you can see the image https://postfiles.pstatic.net/MjAxOTA4MjdfMjk5/MDAxNTY2ODkwMzE0NzM5.NTRPIe18COjt66Pm4SwDvrYy8PNzc-21n7ETVP2_tQ4g.x3TjnWXa71dGbHtLuRY9xzLAxuRmVYeNnAq3GnYbGL8g.PNG.howdy_amigo/image.png?type=w966 
here

```py
preds = np.round(cnn.predict(X_test), 0)

emotions = ['neutral', 'angry', 'disgust', 'fear', 'happy', 'sad', 'surprise']
classification_metrics = metrics.classification_report(y_test, preds, target_names=emotions)
print(classification_metrics)

categorical_test_labels = pd.DataFrame(y_test).idxmax(axis=1)
categorical_preds = pd.DataFrame(preds).idxmax(axis=1)
print("-------------", categorical_test_labels.shape, categorical_preds.shape)

confusion_matrix = confusion_matrix(categorical_test_labels, categorical_preds)

def plot_confusion_matrix(cm, classes, normalize=False, title='confusion matrix', cmap=plt.cm.Blues):
    if normalize:
        cm = cm.astype('float')/cm.sum(axis=1)[:,np.newaxis]
        print('normalized confusion matrix')
    else:
        print('confusion matrix, without normalization')

    plt.imshow(cm, interpolation='nearest', cmap=cmap)

    plt.title(title)
    plt.colorbar()
    tick_marks = np.arange(len(classes))
    plt.xticks(tick_marks, classes, rotation=45)
    plt.yticks(tick_marks, classes)

    fmt = '.2f' if normalize else 'd'
    thresh = cm.max() / 2.
    for i, j in itertools.product(range(cm.shape[0]),range(cm.shape[1])):
        plt.text(j, i, format(cm[i,j], fmt), horizontalalignment='center', color='white' if cm[i, j]>thresh else 'black')

    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.ylabel('true label')
    plt.xlabel('predicted label')
    plt.show()
    plt.savefig('confusion_matrix_epoch11.png')

plot_confusion_matrix(confusion_matrix, emotions, normalize=True)
```

i expect the output of confusion matrix to be square

Comment: What version of Matplotlib are you using? Your function works for me (using `np.random.randint(0, 100, (7, 7))` as input.

Comment: @tomjn i'm using 3.1.1 version of Matplotlib

Comment: Interesting, it works ok with 3.1.0 but not with 3.1.1. It might be worth seeing if there is an issue open on GitHub and open one if not